# AWS VPC DNS Hostnames & Resolution

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

I'm trying to educate myself more on how DNS works, and am struggling with trying out some options in my AWS VPC.

From the AWS Documentation on VPC, there are 2 DNS settings to choose from, DNS Hostnames & DNS Resolution. It states that the following will happen if they are disabled

> If either or both of the attributes is set to false, the following
> occurs:
>
> 1. Instances with a public IP address **do not receive corresponding public DNS hostnames.**
> 2. The Amazon Route 53 Resolver cannot resolve Amazon-provided private DNS hostnames.

To try this out, I spun up an EC2 instance inside a VPC meeting this condition. In the EC2 console, it is correctly not advertising a DNS name. However, if I perform an nslookup on the ip, it gives a DNS name, seemingly conflicting with the documentation.
[image]

Is this actually correct, and I am just thinking about this wrong? What is the point of just having it not advertised in the console, when it actually does seemingly exist behind the scenes? I feel like I am missing something pretty big here or mixing something up.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That's the PTR record set for that IP. Have a read through
[this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_DNS_lookup) to see what this is.